# Sorting across joined collections

Tags: mongodb, sorting, meteor

I have two collections,

1. Products
2. Offers

Offers are children of products, related through the `product` key. Products are related to users via the `user` key:

```
products : function(){
  return Products.find({'user': Meteor.userId()}).fetch();
},
offers: function(){
  return Offers.find({product: this._id}).fetch();
}
```

html:

```
{{#each products}}
  {{#each offers}}

  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

I want to apply sorting in mongodb for offers.price
When I am applying, it is only sorting within each product
How can I sort by `Offers.price` across all products?

Comment: It's helpful if you show an example or otherwise be extremely explicit about what you are trying to accomplish. It sounds like you want to have offers be sorted and in the outer loop, but I'm not sure.

Comment: yup @DavidWeldon , i want to have offers be sorted and in the outer loop (products)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a nested loop of two collections and sort by the inner one:

```
{{#each products}}
  {{#each offers}}

  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

At least in general this is not possible because (in general) product "A" could have the highest price offer and also the lowest.

What you can do is to create a joined array of products and offers and then sort that array by the price key. Since an offer is a child of a product, you can do:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  joinedArray() {
    let array = [];
    Products.find({ 'user': Meteor.userId() }).forEach(p => {
      Offers.find({ product: p._id }).forEach(o => {
        array.push({ productName: p.name, offerName: o.name, offerPrice: o.price });
      });
    });
    return _.sortBy(array,'offerPrice');
  }
});
```

Sorting is done using underscore's [sortBy](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) function.

In the `array.push` line I've made some assumptions about what keys exist in your collections, which ones you want to return in your helper, and how you might want to name those. In the sort I've assumed you want to sort in order of ascending price. If you want the opposite order then you can [.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) it.

If your `Offers` collection was denormalized and included the relevant fields from `Products` then you could just sort that collection directly and use the keys from it in your helper in a single loop.

Comment: Thanks, good idea... but the forEach() takes a callback function.
    
`Products.find({'user': Meteor.userId()}).forEach(function(p){}`

Comment: To quote Homer Simpson, "Doh!"

Answer (score 0):

Sort with something like this:

```
return Offers.find({}, {sort: {price: 1}});
```

But I don't know exactly what you're trying to do here.